# From curve to surface of revolution

Tags: python

I have only curve with arrays of x,y,z points

```
xvals=[0 0 0...]
yvals=[2 1 1...]
zvals=[1 1 1...]
```

How can I make any surface of revolution(rotating a curve around an any axis of rotation)? I do

```
x = np.arange (0, 0.1, 0.005)
y = np.arange (0, 2*np.pi, 0.005)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x=xgrid
y=ygrid
z=zvals
fig = pylab.figure()
axes = Axes3D(fig)
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z)
```

But it isn't surface of revolution. Where is the problem?

Comment: note that you must make sure that `z = f(x, y)`. In other words, `x`, `y` and `z` **must** be of the same `shape`

Comment: Yes, I haven't any function like z = f(x, y), only x,y,z-arrays